# Rails 3 help double rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get an error in view that says that I cannot double render.

My controller:

```
def index
    @title = 'asdsadas'
    @kategoris = Tag.all
    render 'admin/kategoris/index'
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @kategoris }
    end

end
```

How should I rewrite my action, to not double rendering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def index
    @title = 'asdsadas'
    @kategoris = Tag.all

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'admin/kategoris/index' }
    format.json { render :json => @kategoris }
    end

end
```

Comment: This looks like the right answer. The example code in the original question ALWAYS renders 'admin/kategoris/index', and if the format is JSON, then the JSON render also happens - hence double-render.